How to write custom functions that you can apply to columns in purrrr
I need to apply a custom function to a set of columns in a dataset and return a list. I can do this in lapply() but I am trying to work with purrr.
Toy data. Three factor variables
df <- data.frame(variableA = factor(sample(x = c("lessThan", "moreThan"),
                                           size = 20,
                                           replace = T,
                                           prob = c(0.5, 0.5))),
                 variableB = factor(sample(x = c("lessThan", "moreThan"),
                                           size = 20,
                                           replace = T,
                                           prob = c(0.2, 0.8))),
                 variableC = factor(sample(x = c("lessThan", "moreThan"),
                                           size = 20,
                                           replace = T,
                                           prob = c(0.4, 0.6)))) 

Now we create the function, one that returns a dataframe breaking down the proportions of each level of the outcome variable, which we pass into the function as a string.
countMoreLessFunct <- function(data, var) {
  data %>%
    group_by(.data[[var]]) %>%
      summarise(count = n()) %>%
        ungroup %>%
          mutate(tot = sum(count),
                 perc = round(x = count/tot*100,
                              digits = 2))
}

The function works fine with a single variable.
countMoreLessFunct(data = df,
                   var = "variableA")

# output
#   variableA count   tot  perc
#   <fct>     <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1 lessThan     11    20    55
# 2 moreThan      9    20    45

It also works with lapply()
lapply(names(df), function(i) countMoreLessFunct(df, i))

But when I try it in purrr I get all sorts of errors
df %>%
  map(.f = ~countMoreLessFunct(df, .x))

The above, for example, returns the error
# Error in `map()`:
#   ℹ In index: 1.
# ℹ With name: variableA.
# Caused by error in `group_by()`:
#   ℹ In argument: `.data[[structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, `.
# Caused by error in `.data[[<fct>]]`:
#   ! Must subset the data pronoun with a string, not a <factor> object. 

I am lost. The problem obviously lies in the original function, the fact that it requires a string maybe? Any help appreciated

Maybe: names(df) |> map(.f = \(i) countMoreLessFunct(df, i))

Thank you @Edward. I'm afraid I don't understand your code, for example what does \(i) do? Is there any way to get the same effect with the data frame at the top of the pipe chain?

i.e. how would I rewrite the function so i can start with the dataframe? df %>% map(.f = countMoreLessFunct(foo)) or something like that?

Just to make this absolutely clear: the issue isn’t your function, or map. If a function works with lapply, it works with map as well. The issue is that you are calling the functions on different objects! Once on names(df), and once on df. Again, this has nothing to do with your function, or with lapply vs. map.

In your example, map iterates over the column contents (factors) rather than the column names your function expects. You can use {purrr}'s imap instead, which provides the index/name under .y:
df %>%
  imap(.f = ~countMoreLessFunct(df, .y))

Since you're into using {purrr}, you could also create your dataframe by mapping a list of "less-than" probabilities:
df <- list(.5, .2, .4) |> 
  map_dfc( ~ sample(x = c("lessThan", "moreThan"),
                    size = 20, replace = TRUE,
                    prob = c(.x, 1 - .x)
                    ) |> factor()
  ) |> 
  setNames(nm = paste0('variable', LETTERS[1:3])) 


Thank you @I_O. So the problem map had with my function is that it included the group_by([[.var]]) line, which required the inclusion of the variable name as an argument. imap is very neat thank you. I wonder if there is any way to re-write my function so it plays nicely with map and returns a list of dataframes?
